# htaccess mod_rewrite subdomains inheriting rules from main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect `m.example.com` to `example.com/index.php?type=mobile` while inheriting the rules I've already written for `example.com`...

So, say, I have N rules already defined looking something like:

```
^view/([A-z]+) index.php?view=$1
^delete/([A-z]+) index.php?delete=$1
^page/view/([A-z]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?view=$1&page=$2
^page/delete/([A-z]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?delete=$1&page=$2
```

Without having to rewrite each of those for the `m.example.com` subdomain, is there a way for `m.example.com` to inherit the same rules, but with the subdomain flag `type=mobile`? Basically, without having to add N more lines for an .htaccess located in the `m` subdomain folder:

```
^view/([A-z]+) index.php?view=$1&type=mobile
^delete/([A-z]+) index.php?delete=$1&type=mobile
^page/view/([A-z]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?view=$1&page=$2&type=mobile
^page/delete/([A-z]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?delete=$1&page=$2&type=mobile
```

Comment: @gumbo - what's with the change from domain.com to example.com - and btw, any solution idea?

Comment: *example.com* is together with other domain names a reserved domain name for testing and documentation purposes (see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606). *example.com* is just a neutral domain name.

Comment: curiously, example.com appears to be the only reserved name that hasn't been (http://test.com) commercialized or personalized (http://invalid.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply check the *HTTP_HOST* within your PHP script:

```
$mobile = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) === 'm.example.com';
```

Comment: ok that's a neat trick - does HTTP_HOST point to the right domain/subdomain in all cases, or is it like some $_SERVER variables which might be blank sometimes (HTTP_REFERER, for example)?

Comment: @ina: *HTTP\_HOST* is the value from the HTTP header field *Host*. It may be missing if the client uses HTTP 1.0 (that’s the reason for `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])`).

Comment: if that's the case, any suggestions on backup for clients who use HTTP 1.0?

Comment: @ina: No. If the client does not send this information, there is chance to distinguish what host was requested. Except when you have different IP addresses for the standard and mobile variants. Another option would be to inspect the User Agent string.

Comment: user agent can easily be faked though.. so the HTTP_HOST is from client, and not from serverside.. I guess figuring out the htaccess mod_rewrite would be the only sure way to catch the other cases?

Comment: @ina: No, if the client does not send a *Host* field in the request, *HTTP\_HOST* is not available in mod_rewrite neither. And faking the User Agent string is useless pointless in this case as it would only be used to distinguish the variant of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

So try something new:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^view/([A-z]+) index.php?view=$1&type=%1
```

Is that what are you searching for ?